# Show that a sinusoid having a frequency larger than one corresponds to a sinusoid having a frequency less than one.

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

I am studying electrical engineering for fun online. There is this one solution to a question on an online textbook that does not make any sense to me.

The question is:

Show that $\cos(2\pi fn)=\cos(2 \pi (f+1)n)$, which means that a sinusoid having a frequency larger than one corresponds to a sinusoid having a frequency less than one. From [here](http://cnx.org/contents/b64b163b-9da8-4458-b943-7ca267109686@16/The_Fundamental_Signal)

The given solution is:

As $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)−\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$, $\cos(2\pi (f+1)n)=\cos(2 \pi fn)\cos(2 \pi n)−\sin(2\pi fn)\sin(2\pi n)=\cos(2\pi fn)$.

Unless I'm misreading their solution, they're basically saying that $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)−\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = \cos(\alpha)$? Which is obviously NOT right.

So does $\cos(2 \pi fn)=\cos(2 \pi(f+1)n)$? And if so how do you prove it?

Comment: What are the values of $\cos(2\pi n)$ and $\sin(2\pi n)$ when $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Cos(2πn)'s value would be 1 always. And  sin(2πn)'s would be 0 always. . . Which essentially means that the +2πn term in cos(2π(f+1)n) is a 360 * n (integer) degrees phase shift! Meaning  cos(2πfn)=cos(2π(f+1)n). I get it now! Thank you

Comment: The point of the question is simply that if you add a multiple of $2 \pi$ to the argument of a cosine, then the value of the cosine does not change. This is elementary mathematics. Where you go wrong is to interpret this as meaning that you can increase the frequency of a signal, and the signal remains the same. The cosine is function of frequency and time. So only under special conditions the result is true, not in general.

Comment: You really don't need to do any trig identities,
$\cos(2\pi (f+1)n) = \cos(2\pi f n + 2\pi n) = \cos(2\pi f n)$ since the period of cosine is $2\pi$. This only works when $\beta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul helped me answer my question.

When n is an integer, $\cos(2\pi n)$'s value would be 1 always. And $\sin(2πn)$'s would be 0 always. . . Which essentially means that the $+2πn$ term in $\cos(2π(f+1)n)$ is a $360 * n (integer) degrees$ phase shift! Meaning $\cos(2πfn)=\cos(2π(f+1)n)$. I get it now! Thank you